# Function to remove certain rows from dataframe

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement, na

I am attempting to write a function which removes certain rows from the dataframe. 
For simplicity, let us assume that the condition for removal is that there is atleast one NA in the row.

```
    df = data.frame(c("A","B","C"),c(1,NA,3))
fn = function (d) {

  for (x in 1:nrow(d)) { for (y in 1:ncol(d)) {
if(is.na(d[x,y])) d = d[-x,] 
 }}}

fn(df)
```

PS: I am aware that there are better ways to remove rows with atleast one NA, i.e. df = df[-which(!complete.cases(df)] but I am interested to find out why the code I wrote does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly return `d` from your function

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c("A","B","C"), X2 = c(1,NA,3))
fn <- function (d) {
  for (x in 1:nrow(d)) {
    for (y in 1:ncol(d)) {
      if(is.na(d[x,y])) d = d[-x,] 
    }
  }
d # return d
}

fn(df)

> fn(df)
  X1 X2
1  A  1
3  C  3
```

R implicitly returns the result of the last operation, but this is the result of evaluating `if (...)` for the third row, which returned `NULL`

```
> foo <- fn(df) # using your fn()
> foo
NULL
```

You can explicitly call `return(d)` at the end of the function, but that as R is also calling `return()` on the last statement, this is like calling `return(return(d))`. As a result, you can just use `d` on the last line of the function and R does the right thing.

The main exception to not using `return()` (i.e. when you should use it) is in situations where you may want to return early from a function.

Finally, rather than loop over both the rows and the cols of the object, consider just working row-wise. R is vectorised so you can do `is.na()` (for example) on an entire row, and then your `if()` statement would be `if (any(is.na(d[i, ]))` where `i` is the loop index, for example:

```
fn2 <- function (d) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
    if (any(is.na(d[i,]))) {
      d <- d[-i, ]
    }
  }
d # return d
}

> fn2(df)
  X1 X2
1  A  1
3  C  3
```

There are more efficient ways to do even this, but if you think in a vectorised way, you'll start writing simpler and quicker R code.

Answer (score 0):

**Functional programming style**

I think that what OP is missing is that you cannot modify a variable passed as argument directly. That's functional programming style.

Visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

In fact the variable in the body of the function is a copy of the one passed as argument. So you are working on a copy.

That's why you have to return the copy and re-assign it to the variable.

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c("A","B","C"), X2 = c(1,NA,3))
fn <- function (d) {
        for (x in 1:nrow(d)) {
          for (y in 1:ncol(d)) {
            if(is.na(d[x,y])) d = d[-x,]}}
         d} # return d

df <- fn(df)
```

`df` is now as OP wishes